# AWS ELB cannot be accessed via iphone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

As the title implies, I can't seem to access my web app ([r24-staging.resourcefull.cc](https://r24-staging.resourcefull.cc)) using any iphone device with any browser on iphone. But I can access it in any browser on Linux/Windows.

The Web App is hosted in AWS with EC2 and ELB.

Any help where should I start debugging the problem?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you hit the EC2 server directly - without the ELB? As far as debugging this will at least cut the problem in half.

Comment: Hi @DanielSims, no. If I access EC2's IPv4 in iphone's browser directly, it is fine.

Comment: What about when you try to hit the ELB's IPv4 directly (instead of host)? What region is your EC2 in? Here is an interesting site which references a similar issue and suggests latency might be to blame. (Hard to believe when it comes to AWS, though.) https://community.cloudflare.com/t/ssl-causing-website-to-not-load-at-all/39764/32

Comment: @DanielSims, hitting ELB's IPv4 directly is the same as hitting the host. EC2 is in `ap-southeast-2`. Also I don't think latency is the one to blame here because many of us have tried to access the host from different parts of the world.

Comment: Okay, thanks for checking those things. I hope that crossing those off questions off the list will help someone to come to a speedy solution. I wish I had the answer to this one. Will be following.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I can hit the address with iPhone now. Very curious what was going on.

Comment: Yes. Turns out iphone cannot access my site with http 2 enabled on my Load Balancer. So I disabled http 2 temporarily.